# When Logging from a Domino Java Agent, how do I get rid of static text "Agent Error:"

Tags: java, logging, lotus-domino, agent

I'm trying to use the java.util.Logger build into the JVM to log details about a agent run.

I successfully configured the server to allow me to use the FINE,FINEST,and FINER levels.

Every time I use logger, the console output always inserts 'agent  error:'

```
[0F48:0016-03F8] 06/07/2018 10:56:57 PM  Agent Manager: Agent  error: [2018-06-07 22:56:57] [SEVERE ] test severe logging com.xpagesbeast 
[0F48:0016-03F8] 06/07/2018 10:56:57 PM  Agent Manager: Agent  error: [2018-06-07 22:56:57] [WARNING] test warning logging com.xpagesbeast 
[0F48:0016-03F8] 06/07/2018 10:56:57 PM  Agent Manager: Agent  error: [2018-06-07 22:56:57] [INFO   ] test info logging com.xpagesbeast 
[0F48:0016-03F8] 06/07/2018 10:56:57 PM  Agent Manager: Agent  error: [2018-06-07 22:56:57] [FINER  ] test finer logging com.xpagesbeast 
[0F48:0016-03F8] 06/07/2018 10:56:57 PM  Agent Manager: Agent  error: [2018-06-07 22:56:57] [FINEST ] test finest loggin com.xpagesbeast 
[0F48:0016-03F8] 06/07/2018 10:56:57 PM  Agent Manager: Agent  error: [2018-06-07 22:56:57] [FINE   ] testing fine logging
```

I tried using a custom Formatter, which you can see with the brackets [] after Agent  error:

Somewhere, the Agent Manager is intercepting and wrapping my log message with its log message to the console.

How can I get rid of the Agent error: when writing basic output to the console using Logger?